# Async Python 3 HTTP-Server without any ready-made web-frameworks. How?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, webserver

I have a server on python:

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("Hello, World!".encode("utf-8"))


    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("POST!".encode("utf-8"))

webServer = HTTPServer(("", serverPort), Server)
print(f"Server started at http://localhost:{serverPort}")

try:
    webServer.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

But this server works synchronously.

Is it possible to create async HTTP-server without using ready-made web frameworks? If yes, how?

I tried to do this:

```py
webServer = ThreadingHTTPServer(("", serverPort), Server)
print(f"Server started at http://localhost:{serverPort}")
```

instead of this:

```py
webServer = HTTPServer(("", serverPort), Server)
print(f"Server started at http://localhost:{serverPort}")
```

But i am not sure, that it is working.

Comment: module [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)

Comment: module [tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html)

Comment: @furas thank you, but I want to do async server WITHOUT any ready web-frameworks.

Comment: then you will have to write all from scratch.

Comment: BTW: as for me `http.server` and `aiohttp` are on the same level. Both are only web-servers, not web-frameworks. If you don't want to use `aiohttp` then you shouldn't use `http.server`

Comment: @furas I have a testing task in my University. And I can't use any ready-made web-frameworks

Comment: first: `aiohttp` is not `web-framework` but `http-server` like `http.server`. Maybe you simply can't use any external module. Then you will have to write from scratch using standard `async` or [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Answer (score 1):

As per @furas's suggestion, I created a sample server based on [doc](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/#server-example):

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    print('Request served!')
    return web.Response(text=text)

async def run_web_server():
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                    web.get('/{name}', handle)])
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, 'localhost', 8080)
    await site.start()

async def run_other_task():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(run_web_server())
loop.run_until_complete(run_other_task())
loop.run_forever()
```